# How to calculate position from 3 dimensional acceleration data?

Tags: physics

I discussed this problem yesterday with Pickett [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18157262#18157262). We concluded that the best solution may be just `Interpolate` and then `NIntegrate` to get the position vector. I also suggested smoothing but as Pickett commented you can lose important details with it.

**How to calculate the position from acceleration data in *Mathematica*?**

*Example where moving to one direction and other directions about the same*

```
Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=jZ57mqZT"]
```

or

```
time_tick,acc_X_value,acc_Y_value,acc_Z_value
0.008387,-7.051625,-0.432767,-6.701011
0.041984,-7.308113,-0.712300,-6.199558
0.074841,-6.989672,-1.105712,-6.235771
0.108211,-7.580313,-0.931228,-5.587518
0.141834,-7.547990,-0.979114,-5.437576
0.174273,-7.075867,-1.138783,-6.130123
0.208107,-7.554275,-0.835906,-5.692567
0.240980,-7.329661,-0.960558,-5.710225
0.274663,-7.546344,-0.690752,-5.827994
0.308129,-6.949119,-0.860447,-6.631278
0.341972,-6.716275,-0.842939,-6.727797
0.374906,-7.340585,-0.757642,-6.366709
0.408325,-6.646092,-0.905340,-6.730790
0.440989,-6.814441,-1.069348,-6.686945
0.474559,-7.092926,-0.681474,-6.726151
0.508442,-6.090618,-0.887832,-7.290455
0.541162,-7.464041,-0.712600,-6.281712
0.574674,-6.314932,-0.937214,-6.787804
0.608281,-6.961689,-0.820642,-6.581596
0.641125,-7.042347,-0.777395,-6.264054
0.674738,-6.658662,-0.941104,-6.425518
0.708979,-6.956152,-0.764526,-6.639957
0.741439,-6.618408,-0.791462,-6.837934
0.774397,-6.924129,-0.730108,-6.721961
```

Comment: Its not so much that smoothing will lose details its that you don't know what the acceleration was between timestamps.  You have to assume some kind of interpolation (even linear interpolation is an assumption) and each different interpolation scheme will give you a different position; that is your "model risk".

Comment: Have you checked [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068197/how-to-determine-relative-position-using-accelerometer-and-gyro-data)? :)

Comment: Following the link  ↑↑↑ you have [that youtube video](http://youtu.be/C7JQ7Rpwn2k?t=23m20s).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming that all the initial positions (`x[0]`, `y[0]` and `z[0]`) and the initial velocities (`x'[0]`, `y'[0]` and `z'[0]`) are equal to `0` you can do:

```
adat = Rest@Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=jZ57mqZT"];
{ax, ay, az} = Interpolation /@ (adat[[All, {1, #}]] & /@ {2, 3, 4});
{xt, yt, zt} = (x /. Quiet@First@NDSolve[{
        x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0,
        x''[t] == #[t]
        }, x, {t, First@adat[[All, 1]], Last@adat[[All, 1]]}] & /@ {ax, ay, az});


Plot[{ax[t], ay[t], az[t]}, {t, First@adat[[All, 1]],Last@adat[[All, 1]]}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Acceleration", Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Aceleration"}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[{xt[t], yt[t], zt[t]}, {t, First@adat[[All, 1]], Last@adat[[All, 1]]}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Positions", Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Position"}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ParametricPlot3D[{xt[t], yt[t], zt[t]}, {t, First@adat[[All, 1]], Last@adat[[All, 1]]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, -2}, {-1, 1}, {0, -2}}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: If you switch between InterpolationOrders and Methods do you end up in (very) different final positions?

Answer (score 10):

A different interpretation would be that the acceleration is always in the same direction, but that the sensor actually rotates. In that case:

```
{pt, px, py, pz} = Transpose@Rest@Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=jZ57mqZT"];
{pa, pθ, pϕ} = Transpose@CoordinateTransform["Cartesian" -> "Spherical", Transpose@{px, py, pz}];

θi = Interpolation[Transpose@{pt, pθ}];
ϕi = Interpolation[Transpose@{pt, pϕ}];
ai = Interpolation[Transpose@{pt, pa}];
```

Using [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) and assuming that the acceleration data is the acceleration observed in an object (as opposed to measured within the object)

```
hi = (h /. 
    First@Quiet@
      NDSolve[{h[0] == 0, h'[0] == 0, h''[t] == -ai[t]}, 
       h, {t, Min@pt, Max@pt}]);
```

So we can plot the elevation and azimuthal angle

```
ListLinePlot[{pθ, pϕ}, PlotRange -> {-2 π, 2 π}, FrameTicks ->{Automatic, π Range[-2, 2]}, Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "Orientation", FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Angles"}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

The acceleration

```
Plot[hi[t], {t, Min@pt, Max@pt}, Frame -> True,  PlotLabel -> "Trajectory", FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Hight"}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

And the trajectory of an object accelerating as in the data

```
Plot[hi[t], {t, Min@pt, Max@pt}, Frame -> True,  PlotLabel -> "Trajectory", FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Hight"}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

To visualize the orientation over time

```
Animate[
 Graphics3D[
  {
   Opacity[1]
   , Red
   , Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}]
   , Green
   , Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}]
   , Blue
   , Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]
   , Opacity[0.2]
   , GeometricTransformation[
    Cuboid[{-(1/2), -(1/2), -(1/2)}, {1/2, 1/2, 1/2}]
    , Composition @@ {RotationTransform[ϕi[t], {0, 0, 1}], 
      RotationTransform[θi[t], {0, 1, 0}]}
    ]
   }, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}], {t, Min@pt, Max@pt}]
```

[image]

Now that [I figured out](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63259/10397) how to do `Composition` transformations just for eye candy we could mix the trajectory with the rotation angle.

WARNING I'm mixing pears and oranges here, this is misleading and the reality here depends on the details on how and where the acceleration was measured. The data can NOT come from an accelerometer on a falling cube with initial velocity zero (as in the animation) as the acceleration measured in free fall would be minimal until terminal velocity is reached. If the acceleration if measured from 'outside' then we could not measure the angles.

The angles were estimated assuming that gravity acceleration always points down, and the observed magnitude (`Norm`) was fairly constant and close to $\vec{g}$ assuming units of $m/s^2$. If this comes from an accelerometer, like the ones in a phone, implies that it was not falling, but just hanging.

Therefore, this animation is not a physically accurate picture, just fun with Mathematica.

```
Animate[
 Grid[{{
    Graphics3D[
     {
      Opacity[1]
      , Red
      , Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}]
      , Green
      , Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}]
      , Blue
      , Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]
      , Opacity[0.2]
      , GeometricTransformation[
       Cuboid[{-(1/2), -(1/2), -(1/2)}, {1/2, 1/2, +(1/2)}]
       , Composition @@ {
         TranslationTransform[{0, 0, hi[t]}]
         , RotationTransform[ϕi[t], {0, 0, 1}]
         , RotationTransform[θi[t], {0, 1, 0}]

         }]
      }
     , PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-5, 2}}
     , ImageSize -> 300]
    ,
    , Plot[hi[tt], {tt, Min@pt, Max@pt}, Frame -> True, 
     PlotLabel -> "Trajectory", FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Hight"}, 
     ImageSize -> 600, 
     Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Point[{t, hi[t]}]}]
    }}], {t, Table[ti[k], {k, 1, 24, 0.1}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Could you explain or link for reference about `{{{Cos[θi[t]] Cos[ϕi[t]], -Sin[ϕi[t]],  Cos[ϕi[t]] Sin[θi[t]]}, {Cos[θi[t]] Sin[ϕi[t]], Cos[ϕi[t]], Sin[θi[t]] Sin[ϕi[t]]}, {-Sin[θi[t]], 0, Cos[θi[t]]}}`

Comment: @JunhoLee It came from composing the two rotations by hand, now I do it more elegantly.

Comment: Aha thanks a lot :)

Comment: Correct this data is measured by having the phone in hand, well-observed -- nice visualisation +1!