# Compose many Geometric Transformations for 3D Graphics

Tags: matrix, graphics3d, geometric-transform, coordinate-transformation, rotation

I'm struggling to understand what would be a good way to **compose several geometrical  transformations to create a single [`TransformationFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformationFunction.html)** to be applied to a  [`GeometricTransformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricTransformation.html). One way could be to obtain a set of [`TransformationMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformationMatrix.html) and multiply.

On [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63197/how-to-calculate-position-from-3-dimensional-acceleration-data/63198#answer-63253) what I would have liked to achieve is to perform two rotations in different axis and then a translation in order to create a realistic trajectory of a falling cube, knowing height *vs* time and also the angles of elevation and azimuth *vs* time.

If I give a list of transformation functions these are applied to different copies of the original object instead of the same in sequence

```
Graphics3D[{
  Opacity[1]
  , Red
  , Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}]
  , Green
  , Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}]
  , Blue
  , Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]
  , Opacity[0.2]
  , GeometricTransformation[Cuboid[-{1, 1, 1}/4, {1, 1, 1}/4],
   {
    RotationTransform[Pi/4, {0, 0, 1}]
    , TranslationTransform[{1, 1, 1}]
    }
   ]
  }]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

**How do I properly compose several sequential geometrical transformations ?**

Comment: I figure out the solution as soon as I posted the question and read one of the **Related** posts. I'm not sure if I should delete this or not. Anyhow I'm looking forward for other better solutions.

Comment: You can use `Fold` too, but matrix multiplication may be slightly faster: [How to render a 3D ellipsoid with Graphics3D?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35043/5478)

Comment: FYI: There is nothing wrong with answering your own question.  In fact it is a recommended practice if you have something particularly nice you wish to share e.g. [(54784)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54784/121).  See: [(834)](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/834/121)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html) I can apply `RotationTransform`, `TranslationTransform` , `ShearingTransform` one after the other.

```
Graphics3D[{
  Opacity[1]
  , Red
  , Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}]
  , Green
  , Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}]
  , Blue
  , Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]
  , Opacity[0.2]
  , GeometricTransformation[Cuboid[-{1, 1, 1}/4, {1, 1, 1}/4],
   Composition @@ {
     RotationTransform[Pi/4, {0, 0, 1}]
     , TranslationTransform[{1, 1, 1}]
     , ShearingTransform[Pi/8, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}]
     }
   ]
  }]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I did not know that `Composition` would combine `*Transform` expressions in this manner so you just taught me something.  Thanks and +1.