# Position from 3 dimensional acceleration data?

Tags: numerical-integration, interpolation, physics, filtering, signal-processing

Per a previous post on Mathematica StackExchange [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63197/how-to-calculate-position-from-3-dimensional-acceleration-data) I'm trying to utilize 3-axis accelerometer data to determine approximate 3D position. I wanted to start with a simple case. To this end I've employed a hand drill, wood plate and  [HOBO Pendant G Logger](http://www.onsetcomp.com/products/data-loggers/ua-004-64). The accelerometer was mounted at one edge of the plate and rotated by the drill at approximately 20 rpm. Drill was held in a vice with the z-axis perpendicular and x- and y- axes in the plane of rotation. Sample rate was 100 Hz.

[image: HOBO Pendant G mounted to a wood plate and rotated via hand drill. Drill was held in a vice with the z-axis nearly perpendicular and x- and y- axes in the plane of rotation.]

A five-second snip of the data is presented below:

```
time,x_g,y_g,z_g,sum_g,x_deg,y_deg,z_deg
15.00,0.925,0.525,0.825,1.346,157.7,121.7,145.6
15.01,0.975,0.525,1.05,1.526,167.2,121.7,180
15.02,0.925,0.575,1.175,1.602,157.7,125.1,180
15.03,1.075,0.525,1.025,1.575,180,121.7,180
15.04,0.9,0.525,1.15,1.552,154.2,121.7,180
15.05,1,0.5,1,1.5,180,120,180
15.06,0.85,0.525,0.925,1.362,148.2,121.7,157.7
15.07,0.925,0.55,0.7,1.284,157.7,123.4,134.4
15.08,0.825,0.5,1,1.389,145.6,120,180
15.09,1.05,0.65,1.125,1.671,180,130.5,180
15.10,1.075,0.55,1.1,1.633,180,123.4,180
15.11,1.025,0.575,1.1,1.61,180,125.1,180
15.12,1.05,0.525,1.25,1.715,180,121.7,180
15.13,1.075,0.625,1.1,1.66,180,128.7,180
15.14,0.875,0.5,0.95,1.385,151,120,161.8
15.15,0.925,0.475,0.775,1.297,157.7,118.4,140.8
15.16,0.925,0.5,1.075,1.504,157.7,120,180
15.17,1,0.575,1.15,1.629,180,125.1,180
15.18,1,0.6,1.025,1.553,180,126.9,180
15.19,1.1,0.65,1.175,1.736,180,130.5,180
15.20,1.1,0.6,1.325,1.824,180,126.9,180
15.21,0.975,0.575,0.975,1.494,167.2,125.1,167.2
15.22,0.9,0.45,0.7,1.226,154.2,116.7,134.4
15.23,0.925,0.55,0.9,1.403,157.7,123.4,154.2
15.24,0.95,0.575,1.075,1.546,161.8,125.1,180
15.25,0.975,0.575,1.1,1.578,167.2,125.1,180
15.26,1.025,0.55,1,1.534,180,123.4,180
15.27,1.025,0.6,1.2,1.688,180,126.9,180
15.28,0.95,0.65,1.25,1.699,161.8,130.5,180
15.29,1.025,0.575,1.075,1.593,180,125.1,180
15.30,0.925,0.625,0.875,1.418,157.7,128.7,151
15.31,0.875,0.45,0.85,1.3,151,116.7,148.2
15.32,0.9,0.575,0.85,1.365,154.2,125.1,148.2
15.33,0.925,0.475,0.875,1.359,157.7,118.4,151
15.34,0.975,0.6,0.975,1.504,167.2,126.9,167.2
15.35,0.975,0.625,1.225,1.686,167.2,128.7,180
15.36,1.05,0.625,1.35,1.821,180,128.7,180
15.37,0.975,0.6,0.975,1.504,167.2,126.9,167.2
15.38,0.825,0.5,0.825,1.269,145.6,120,145.6
15.39,0.825,0.575,0.9,1.35,145.6,125.1,154.2
15.40,0.9,0.45,0.9,1.35,154.2,116.7,154.2
15.41,0.9,0.55,0.975,1.436,154.2,123.4,167.2
15.42,0.975,0.55,1.15,1.605,167.2,123.4,180
15.43,0.95,0.65,1.15,1.627,161.8,130.5,180
15.44,0.95,0.625,1.05,1.548,161.8,128.7,180
15.45,0.825,0.6,1,1.429,145.6,126.9,180
15.46,0.875,0.525,0.975,1.411,151,121.7,167.2
15.47,0.875,0.575,1.075,1.501,151,125.1,180
15.48,0.975,0.525,1,1.492,167.2,121.7,180
15.49,0.825,0.55,1.05,1.444,145.6,123.4,180
15.50,0.975,0.55,1.025,1.518,167.2,123.4,180
15.51,0.9,0.55,1.15,1.56,154.2,123.4,180
15.52,0.975,0.575,1.15,1.614,167.2,125.1,180
15.53,0.9,0.5,1.075,1.488,154.2,120,180
15.54,0.675,0.75,0.875,1.336,132.5,138.6,151
15.55,0.85,0.525,0.85,1.312,148.2,121.7,148.2
15.56,0.9,0.475,0.975,1.409,154.2,118.4,167.2
15.57,0.9,0.55,1.15,1.56,154.2,123.4,180
15.58,0.925,0.525,1.15,1.566,157.7,121.7,180
15.59,0.875,0.525,0.95,1.394,151,121.7,161.8
15.60,0.75,0.575,0.95,1.34,138.6,125.1,161.8
15.61,0.9,0.6,0.975,1.456,154.2,126.9,167.2
15.62,0.875,0.475,1,1.411,151,118.4,180
15.63,0.975,0.65,1.125,1.624,167.2,130.5,180
15.64,0.975,0.5,1.325,1.719,167.2,120,180
15.65,0.925,0.55,1.175,1.593,157.7,123.4,180
15.66,0.9,0.55,1.05,1.488,154.2,123.4,180
15.67,0.8,0.45,0.85,1.251,143.1,116.7,148.2
15.68,0.8,0.55,0.8,1.258,143.1,123.4,143.1
15.69,0.875,0.525,1.025,1.446,151,121.7,180
15.70,0.95,0.575,1.075,1.546,161.8,125.1,180
15.71,0.95,0.425,1.025,1.461,161.8,115.2,180
15.72,0.875,0.55,1.05,1.473,151,123.4,180
15.73,0.875,0.425,0.95,1.36,151,115.2,161.8
15.74,0.825,0.575,0.875,1.333,145.6,125.1,151
15.75,0.775,0.45,0.975,1.324,140.8,116.7,167.2
15.76,0.925,0.525,0.85,1.362,157.7,121.7,148.2
15.77,0.9,0.475,1.05,1.462,154.2,118.4,180
15.78,0.925,0.475,1.025,1.46,157.7,118.4,180
15.79,0.9,0.475,1.1,1.499,154.2,118.4,180
15.80,0.9,0.475,1.1,1.499,154.2,118.4,180
15.81,0.875,0.575,1.075,1.501,151,125.1,180
15.82,0.95,0.5,1.05,1.502,161.8,120,180
15.83,0.925,0.6,1.075,1.54,157.7,126.9,180
15.84,0.925,0.5,1.025,1.468,157.7,120,180
15.85,0.825,0.475,0.925,1.327,145.6,118.4,157.7
15.86,0.925,0.45,0.825,1.319,157.7,116.7,145.6
15.87,0.95,0.475,1.075,1.511,161.8,118.4,180
15.88,0.975,0.6,1.25,1.695,167.2,126.9,180
15.89,0.95,0.525,1.125,1.563,161.8,121.7,180
15.90,0.95,0.575,0.95,1.461,161.8,125.1,161.8
15.91,0.925,0.575,1.125,1.566,157.7,125.1,180
15.92,0.925,0.55,1.025,1.486,157.7,123.4,180
15.93,0.975,0.475,0.825,1.363,167.2,118.4,145.6
15.94,1,0.475,0.975,1.475,180,118.4,167.2
15.95,1,0.575,1.15,1.629,180,125.1,180
15.96,1.025,0.575,1.275,1.734,180,125.1,180
15.97,0.975,0.65,1.125,1.624,167.2,130.5,180
15.98,0.875,0.475,1,1.411,151,118.4,180
15.99,0.925,0.575,0.875,1.397,157.7,125.1,151
16.00,0.9,0.475,0.825,1.31,154.2,118.4,145.6
16.01,0.925,0.45,0.9,1.367,157.7,116.7,154.2
16.02,1.05,0.575,1.1,1.626,180,125.1,180
16.03,1.025,0.525,1.225,1.681,180,121.7,180
16.04,0.95,0.65,1.1,1.592,161.8,130.5,180
16.05,0.925,0.45,0.9,1.367,157.7,116.7,154.2
16.06,0.875,0.5,0.675,1.213,151,120,132.5
16.07,0.825,0.45,0.85,1.267,145.6,116.7,148.2
16.08,0.9,0.525,1.025,1.462,154.2,121.7,180
16.09,1.075,0.625,1.075,1.644,180,128.7,180
16.10,0.95,0.5,1.25,1.648,161.8,120,180
16.11,0.925,0.625,0.975,1.482,157.7,128.7,167.2
16.12,0.975,0.625,1.2,1.668,167.2,128.7,180
16.13,1,0.6,0.975,1.52,180,126.9,167.2
16.14,0.85,0.5,0.725,1.224,148.2,120,136.5
16.15,0.875,0.55,1,1.438,151,123.4,180
16.16,1.05,0.525,1.225,1.697,180,121.7,180
16.17,1.025,0.7,1.325,1.816,180,134.4,180
16.18,1.025,0.525,1.125,1.61,180,121.7,180
16.19,0.9,0.625,0.975,1.467,154.2,128.7,167.2
16.20,0.875,0.5,1.025,1.437,151,120,180
16.21,0.9,0.575,0.8,1.334,154.2,125.1,143.1
16.22,0.85,0.525,0.95,1.379,148.2,121.7,161.8
16.23,0.95,0.65,1.15,1.627,161.8,130.5,180
16.24,0.975,0.55,1.075,1.552,167.2,123.4,180
16.25,0.925,0.575,1.075,1.53,157.7,125.1,180
16.26,0.925,0.575,1.05,1.513,157.7,125.1,180
16.27,0.875,0.625,0.975,1.452,151,128.7,167.2
16.28,0.9,0.525,0.925,1.393,154.2,121.7,157.7
16.29,0.875,0.575,0.9,1.381,151,125.1,154.2
16.30,0.925,0.525,0.95,1.426,157.7,121.7,161.8
16.31,0.925,0.525,1.125,1.548,157.7,121.7,180
16.32,0.925,0.6,1.1,1.557,157.7,126.9,180
16.33,0.925,0.65,1.125,1.595,157.7,130.5,180
16.34,0.9,0.6,1.025,1.49,154.2,126.9,180
16.35,0.825,0.575,0.825,1.301,145.6,125.1,145.6
16.36,0.875,0.525,1.025,1.446,151,121.7,180
16.37,0.875,0.625,1.1,1.538,151,128.7,180
16.38,0.925,0.5,1.075,1.504,157.7,120,180
16.39,0.95,0.575,1.025,1.511,161.8,125.1,180
16.40,0.875,0.5,1.1,1.492,151,120,180
16.41,0.9,0.625,1.075,1.535,154.2,128.7,180
16.42,0.9,0.5,1.2,1.581,154.2,120,180
16.43,0.875,0.6,0.95,1.424,151,126.9,161.8
16.44,0.875,0.525,1,1.429,151,121.7,180
16.45,0.9,0.575,1.05,1.498,154.2,125.1,180
16.46,0.925,0.525,1.1,1.53,157.7,121.7,180
16.47,0.875,0.525,1.1,1.5,151,121.7,180
16.48,0.875,0.525,1,1.429,151,121.7,180
16.49,0.75,0.475,0.9,1.264,138.6,118.4,154.2
16.50,0.85,0.625,0.95,1.42,148.2,128.7,161.8
16.51,0.9,0.5,1.025,1.453,154.2,120,180
16.52,0.95,0.525,1.025,1.493,161.8,121.7,180
16.53,0.875,0.5,1.175,1.548,151,120,180
16.54,0.95,0.475,1.1,1.529,161.8,118.4,180
16.55,0.9,0.525,0.975,1.427,154.2,121.7,167.2
16.56,0.875,0.475,1.05,1.447,151,118.4,180
16.57,0.85,0.65,1.1,1.535,148.2,130.5,180
16.58,0.725,0.525,1.075,1.399,136.5,121.7,180
16.59,0.875,0.475,0.85,1.309,151,118.4,148.2
16.60,0.9,0.5,1.05,1.471,154.2,120,180
16.61,0.9,0.525,1.2,1.589,154.2,121.7,180
16.62,0.9,0.525,1.125,1.533,154.2,121.7,180
16.63,0.875,0.525,0.95,1.394,151,121.7,161.8
16.64,0.85,0.5,0.975,1.387,148.2,120,167.2
16.65,0.925,0.525,0.975,1.443,157.7,121.7,167.2
16.66,0.925,0.525,1,1.46,157.7,121.7,180
16.67,0.925,0.525,1.025,1.477,157.7,121.7,180
16.68,0.9,0.5,1.05,1.471,154.2,120,180
16.69,0.9,0.475,0.95,1.392,154.2,118.4,161.8
16.70,0.875,0.525,0.925,1.377,151,121.7,157.7
16.71,0.85,0.475,1.15,1.507,148.2,118.4,180
16.72,0.925,0.5,1.05,1.486,157.7,120,180
16.73,0.95,0.5,0.775,1.324,161.8,120,140.8
16.74,0.875,0.475,0.925,1.359,151,118.4,157.7
16.75,0.9,0.475,1.075,1.48,154.2,118.4,180
16.76,0.975,0.5,0.975,1.467,167.2,120,167.2
16.77,0.95,0.5,1.075,1.519,161.8,120,180
16.78,1,0.525,1.1,1.577,180,121.7,180
16.79,0.9,0.525,1.1,1.515,154.2,121.7,180
16.80,0.975,0.575,0.95,1.478,167.2,125.1,161.8
16.81,0.875,0.475,0.975,1.394,151,118.4,167.2
16.82,0.95,0.575,0.95,1.461,161.8,125.1,161.8
16.83,0.975,0.525,1,1.492,167.2,121.7,180
16.84,1.05,0.525,1.025,1.558,180,121.7,180
16.85,1.025,0.525,1.3,1.737,180,121.7,180
16.86,1.025,0.55,1.2,1.671,180,123.4,180
16.87,0.925,0.5,0.975,1.434,157.7,120,167.2
16.88,0.85,0.55,1,1.423,148.2,123.4,180
16.89,0.975,0.5,1.075,1.535,167.2,120,180
16.90,1,0.625,1.05,1.579,180,128.7,180
16.91,1,0.6,1.2,1.673,180,126.9,180
16.92,1.075,0.625,1.1,1.66,180,128.7,180
16.93,0.925,0.55,1.025,1.486,157.7,123.4,180
16.94,0.975,0.525,0.9,1.427,167.2,121.7,154.2
16.95,0.875,0.5,1.025,1.437,151,120,180
16.96,0.925,0.525,0.875,1.377,157.7,121.7,151
16.97,0.825,0.5,0.9,1.319,145.6,120,154.2
16.98,1,0.6,0.975,1.52,180,126.9,167.2
16.99,1.025,0.55,1.275,1.726,180,123.4,180
17.00,1.025,0.65,1.1,1.638,180,130.5,180
17.01,0.925,0.55,1.075,1.521,157.7,123.4,180
17.02,0.925,0.6,1.15,1.593,157.7,126.9,180
17.03,0.95,0.55,0.975,1.468,161.8,123.4,167.2
17.04,0.95,0.6,1.075,1.555,161.8,126.9,180
17.05,0.975,0.6,1.175,1.641,167.2,126.9,180
17.06,0.975,0.575,1.275,1.705,167.2,125.1,180
17.07,0.975,0.575,1.025,1.527,167.2,125.1,180
17.08,0.9,0.5,0.925,1.384,154.2,120,157.7
17.09,0.9,0.55,1.075,1.506,154.2,123.4,180
17.10,0.925,0.575,1.1,1.548,157.7,125.1,180
17.11,0.925,0.625,0.975,1.482,157.7,128.7,167.2
17.12,0.975,0.675,1.175,1.669,167.2,132.5,180
17.13,0.975,0.65,1.175,1.659,167.2,130.5,180
17.14,0.9,0.575,1,1.463,154.2,125.1,180
17.15,0.875,0.475,0.925,1.359,151,118.4,157.7
17.16,0.875,0.525,0.9,1.361,151,121.7,154.2
17.17,0.875,0.575,1,1.448,151,125.1,180
17.18,0.875,0.525,1.025,1.446,151,121.7,180
17.19,0.9,0.575,0.95,1.429,154.2,125.1,161.8
17.20,0.875,0.5,1.075,1.474,151,120,180
17.21,0.925,0.525,1.1,1.53,157.7,121.7,180
17.22,0.875,0.55,1.025,1.456,151,123.4,180
17.23,0.9,0.525,1.025,1.462,154.2,121.7,180
17.24,0.825,0.575,1,1.418,145.6,125.1,180
17.25,0.825,0.7,1.025,1.49,145.6,134.4,180
17.26,0.925,0.475,1.15,1.55,157.7,118.4,180
17.27,0.825,0.6,1.025,1.446,145.6,126.9,180
17.28,0.875,0.525,1.05,1.464,151,121.7,180
17.29,0.875,0.55,1.025,1.456,151,123.4,180
17.30,0.9,0.5,0.975,1.418,154.2,120,167.2
17.31,0.9,0.55,1.125,1.542,154.2,123.4,180
17.32,0.8,0.625,1.075,1.479,143.1,128.7,180
17.33,0.8,0.5,0.925,1.321,143.1,120,157.7
17.34,0.9,0.5,1.05,1.471,154.2,120,180
17.35,0.825,0.575,1.025,1.436,145.6,125.1,180
17.36,0.825,0.525,1,1.399,145.6,121.7,180
17.37,0.925,0.525,0.975,1.443,157.7,121.7,167.2
17.38,0.825,0.425,0.975,1.346,145.6,115.2,167.2
17.39,0.85,0.575,1,1.433,148.2,125.1,180
17.40,0.875,0.475,1.075,1.465,151,118.4,180
17.41,0.775,0.55,0.925,1.326,140.8,123.4,157.7
17.42,0.875,0.5,0.975,1.402,151,120,167.2
17.43,0.85,0.65,1.025,1.482,148.2,130.5,180
17.44,0.925,0.475,1.1,1.514,157.7,118.4,180
17.45,0.975,0.55,1.1,1.569,167.2,123.4,180
17.46,0.9,0.45,1.075,1.472,154.2,116.7,180
17.47,0.85,0.525,0.925,1.362,148.2,121.7,157.7
17.48,0.8,0.525,0.925,1.331,143.1,121.7,157.7
17.49,0.85,0.425,0.825,1.258,148.2,115.2,145.6
17.50,0.85,0.525,0.825,1.296,148.2,121.7,145.6
17.51,0.875,0.4,1,1.388,151,113.6,180
17.52,0.975,0.525,1.05,1.526,167.2,121.7,180
17.53,0.925,0.5,1.05,1.486,157.7,120,180
17.54,0.9,0.525,1.075,1.497,154.2,121.7,180
17.55,0.875,0.6,1.175,1.583,151,126.9,180
17.56,0.875,0.525,1.05,1.464,151,121.7,180
17.57,1,0.525,0.775,1.37,180,121.7,140.8
17.58,0.775,0.475,1.1,1.427,140.8,118.4,180
17.59,0.975,0.425,0.975,1.443,167.2,115.2,167.2
17.60,0.9,0.5,0.975,1.418,154.2,120,167.2
17.61,0.925,0.475,1.025,1.46,157.7,118.4,180
17.62,0.85,0.5,1,1.404,148.2,120,180
17.63,0.95,0.55,0.85,1.388,161.8,123.4,148.2
17.64,0.875,0.475,0.975,1.394,151,118.4,167.2
17.65,0.875,0.475,0.825,1.293,151,118.4,145.6
17.66,0.875,0.425,0.925,1.342,151,115.2,157.7
17.67,0.975,0.625,1.05,1.563,167.2,128.7,180
17.68,1.025,0.525,1.25,1.7,180,121.7,180
17.69,1.075,0.65,1.275,1.79,180,130.5,180
17.70,1.025,0.575,1.15,1.644,180,125.1,180
17.71,0.85,0.475,0.8,1.26,148.2,118.4,143.1
17.72,0.825,0.45,0.875,1.284,145.6,116.7,151
17.73,0.85,0.475,0.85,1.293,148.2,118.4,148.2
17.74,0.825,0.475,1,1.381,145.6,118.4,180
17.75,1,0.6,1.1,1.603,180,126.9,180
17.76,0.975,0.525,1.275,1.689,167.2,121.7,180
17.77,1.125,0.625,1.175,1.743,180,128.7,180
17.78,0.925,0.525,1.35,1.719,157.7,121.7,180
17.79,1,0.625,1.025,1.562,180,128.7,180
17.80,0.95,0.55,0.95,1.452,161.8,123.4,161.8
17.81,0.975,0.575,1.025,1.527,167.2,125.1,180
17.82,0.95,0.575,1.15,1.599,161.8,125.1,180
17.83,1,0.525,1,1.509,180,121.7,180
17.84,0.975,0.525,0.975,1.475,167.2,121.7,167.2
17.85,0.9,0.525,0.975,1.427,154.2,121.7,167.2
17.86,0.925,0.5,0.95,1.417,157.7,120,161.8
17.87,0.925,0.55,0.85,1.371,157.7,123.4,148.2
17.88,0.9,0.6,1.1,1.543,154.2,126.9,180
17.89,1,0.6,1.1,1.603,180,126.9,180
17.90,1.025,0.55,1.125,1.618,180,123.4,180
17.91,0.975,0.575,1.15,1.614,167.2,125.1,180
17.92,0.9,0.525,0.975,1.427,154.2,121.7,167.2
17.93,0.85,0.55,0.9,1.355,148.2,123.4,154.2
17.94,0.9,0.6,1.15,1.579,154.2,126.9,180
17.95,0.975,0.625,1.175,1.65,167.2,128.7,180
17.96,1.025,0.7,1.225,1.744,180,134.4,180
17.97,1.025,0.625,1.3,1.77,180,128.7,180
17.98,0.975,0.575,1.075,1.561,167.2,125.1,180
17.99,0.925,0.525,1.05,1.495,157.7,121.7,180
18.00,0.9,0.625,1.075,1.535,154.2,128.7,180
18.01,0.9,0.575,1,1.463,154.2,125.1,180
18.02,0.875,0.6,1.025,1.475,151,126.9,180
18.03,0.95,0.525,1,1.476,161.8,121.7,180
18.04,0.925,0.575,1.175,1.602,157.7,125.1,180
18.05,0.975,0.525,1.175,1.615,167.2,121.7,180
18.06,0.875,0.6,1,1.458,151,126.9,180
18.07,0.875,0.525,0.975,1.411,151,121.7,167.2
18.08,0.8,0.6,1.025,1.432,143.1,126.9,180
18.09,0.95,0.575,0.975,1.478,161.8,125.1,167.2
18.10,0.925,0.575,1.15,1.584,157.7,125.1,180
18.11,0.925,0.575,1.125,1.566,157.7,125.1,180
18.12,0.875,0.575,1.025,1.465,151,125.1,180
18.13,0.95,0.5,0.975,1.45,161.8,120,167.2
18.14,0.825,0.525,0.975,1.381,145.6,121.7,167.2
18.15,0.875,0.575,1.025,1.465,151,125.1,180
18.16,0.825,0.525,0.975,1.381,145.6,121.7,167.2
18.17,0.875,0.575,0.95,1.414,151,125.1,161.8
18.18,0.925,0.575,1.025,1.496,157.7,125.1,180
18.19,0.875,0.525,1.025,1.446,151,121.7,180
18.20,0.875,0.525,1.075,1.482,151,121.7,180
18.21,0.9,0.525,1.1,1.515,154.2,121.7,180
18.22,0.875,0.525,0.975,1.411,151,121.7,167.2
18.23,0.875,0.625,1.05,1.503,151,128.7,180
18.24,0.875,0.525,1.1,1.5,151,121.7,180
18.25,0.875,0.55,0.975,1.421,151,123.4,167.2
18.26,0.95,0.5,1.05,1.502,161.8,120,180
18.27,0.875,0.475,1.125,1.502,151,118.4,180
18.28,0.925,0.525,1.05,1.495,157.7,121.7,180
18.29,0.925,0.5,0.925,1.4,157.7,120,157.7
18.30,0.75,0.625,0.85,1.294,138.6,128.7,148.2
18.31,0.85,0.5,1.05,1.44,148.2,120,180
18.32,0.975,0.625,1.05,1.563,167.2,128.7,180
18.33,0.875,0.5,1.225,1.586,151,120,180
18.34,0.925,0.6,1.15,1.593,157.7,126.9,180
18.35,0.925,0.5,1,1.451,157.7,120,180
18.36,0.875,0.55,0.95,1.404,151,123.4,161.8
18.37,0.925,0.5,1.1,1.522,157.7,120,180
18.38,0.95,0.55,1.1,1.554,161.8,123.4,180
18.39,0.875,0.525,1.025,1.446,151,121.7,180
18.40,0.925,0.475,0.925,1.392,157.7,118.4,157.7
18.41,0.875,0.55,0.9,1.37,151,123.4,154.2
18.42,0.9,0.475,0.95,1.392,154.2,118.4,161.8
18.43,0.95,0.525,0.8,1.348,161.8,121.7,143.1
18.44,0.95,0.5,0.95,1.434,161.8,120,161.8
18.45,0.975,0.6,1.2,1.659,167.2,126.9,180
18.46,0.95,0.6,1.2,1.644,161.8,126.9,180
18.47,1,0.55,0.95,1.485,180,123.4,161.8
18.48,0.9,0.525,1,1.444,154.2,121.7,180
18.49,0.925,0.55,0.875,1.387,157.7,123.4,151
18.50,0.875,0.425,0.85,1.292,151,115.2,148.2
18.51,0.975,0.525,0.85,1.396,167.2,121.7,148.2
18.52,0.95,0.475,1.05,1.494,161.8,118.4,180
18.53,1.075,0.625,0.975,1.58,180,128.7,167.2
18.54,0.975,0.55,1.175,1.623,167.2,123.4,180
18.55,1.025,0.55,1.175,1.653,180,123.4,180
18.56,1.025,0.625,1.1,1.628,180,128.7,180
18.57,0.95,0.45,0.925,1.4,161.8,116.7,157.7
18.58,0.925,0.6,0.9,1.423,157.7,126.9,154.2
18.59,0.925,0.4,0.975,1.402,157.7,113.6,167.2
18.60,0.9,0.675,0.975,1.489,154.2,132.5,167.2
18.61,1,0.475,1.125,1.578,180,118.4,180
18.62,1.15,0.7,1.175,1.787,180,134.4,180
18.63,1.025,0.525,1.45,1.852,180,121.7,180
18.64,1,0.6,0.925,1.488,180,126.9,157.7
18.65,0.975,0.45,0.825,1.354,167.2,116.7,145.6
18.66,0.95,0.525,0.925,1.426,161.8,121.7,157.7
18.67,0.875,0.525,0.825,1.312,151,121.7,145.6
18.68,0.9,0.525,1.15,1.552,154.2,121.7,180
18.69,1.025,0.6,1.15,1.653,180,126.9,180
18.70,1,0.6,1.075,1.586,180,126.9,180
18.71,0.975,0.65,1.075,1.59,167.2,130.5,180
18.72,1.025,0.55,1.175,1.653,180,123.4,180
18.73,1.025,0.575,0.95,1.511,180,125.1,161.8
18.74,0.95,0.5,1.025,1.484,161.8,120,180
18.75,1,0.6,1,1.536,180,126.9,180
18.76,0.95,0.6,1.2,1.644,161.8,126.9,180
18.77,0.925,0.65,1.225,1.667,157.7,130.5,180
18.78,0.925,0.575,1.05,1.513,157.7,125.1,180
18.79,0.925,0.575,1.025,1.496,157.7,125.1,180
18.80,0.85,0.475,0.775,1.244,148.2,118.4,140.8
18.81,0.85,0.475,0.725,1.214,148.2,118.4,136.5
18.82,0.925,0.525,1.025,1.477,157.7,121.7,180
18.83,0.925,0.625,1.025,1.516,157.7,128.7,180
18.84,0.925,0.65,1.025,1.526,157.7,130.5,180
18.85,1.025,0.65,1.15,1.672,180,130.5,180
18.86,0.95,0.675,1.125,1.62,161.8,132.5,180
18.87,0.95,0.55,0.975,1.468,161.8,123.4,167.2
18.88,0.9,0.55,1.05,1.488,154.2,123.4,180
18.89,0.925,0.475,0.975,1.425,157.7,118.4,167.2
18.90,0.825,0.575,0.85,1.317,145.6,125.1,148.2
18.91,0.875,0.5,0.975,1.402,151,120,167.2
18.92,0.85,0.675,0.95,1.442,148.2,132.5,161.8
18.93,0.95,0.5,1.05,1.502,161.8,120,180
18.94,0.95,0.55,1.2,1.626,161.8,123.4,180
18.95,0.975,0.575,1,1.51,167.2,125.1,180
18.96,0.9,0.525,0.975,1.427,154.2,121.7,167.2
18.97,0.85,0.575,1.025,1.45,148.2,125.1,180
18.98,0.85,0.65,0.975,1.448,148.2,130.5,167.2
18.99,0.875,0.525,0.925,1.377,151,121.7,157.7
19.00,0.9,0.55,0.925,1.403,154.2,123.4,157.7
19.01,0.825,0.6,1.1,1.5,145.6,126.9,180
19.02,0.925,0.5,1.125,1.54,157.7,120,180
19.03,0.95,0.575,1.025,1.511,161.8,125.1,180
19.04,0.9,0.475,1.1,1.499,154.2,118.4,180
19.05,0.9,0.65,1.075,1.545,154.2,130.5,180
19.06,0.925,0.625,1,1.499,157.7,128.7,180
19.07,0.9,0.525,1.025,1.462,154.2,121.7,180
19.08,0.875,0.575,0.975,1.431,151,125.1,167.2
19.09,0.875,0.55,1,1.438,151,123.4,180
19.10,0.9,0.55,1,1.453,154.2,123.4,180
19.11,0.925,0.45,1.1,1.506,157.7,116.7,180
19.12,0.9,0.575,1.05,1.498,154.2,125.1,180
19.13,0.9,0.55,1.05,1.488,154.2,123.4,180
19.14,0.9,0.625,1.05,1.518,154.2,128.7,180
19.15,0.925,0.525,1.1,1.53,157.7,121.7,180
19.16,0.9,0.525,0.975,1.427,154.2,121.7,167.2
19.17,0.9,0.5,0.95,1.401,154.2,120,161.8
19.18,0.875,0.475,1,1.411,151,118.4,180
19.19,0.9,0.55,1,1.453,154.2,123.4,180
19.20,0.925,0.575,1,1.479,157.7,125.1,180
19.21,0.9,0.55,0.95,1.42,154.2,123.4,161.8
19.22,0.975,0.525,1,1.492,167.2,121.7,180
19.23,0.95,0.575,1.05,1.528,161.8,125.1,180
19.24,0.95,0.475,1.1,1.529,161.8,118.4,180
19.25,0.975,0.55,1.15,1.605,167.2,123.4,180
19.26,1,0.475,1.125,1.578,180,118.4,180
19.27,0.95,0.575,1.1,1.563,161.8,125.1,180
19.28,0.975,0.6,1.2,1.659,167.2,126.9,180
19.29,0.925,0.6,1.2,1.63,157.7,126.9,180
19.30,0.95,0.575,1.05,1.528,161.8,125.1,180
19.31,0.975,0.55,1.025,1.518,167.2,123.4,180
19.32,0.95,0.575,1,1.494,161.8,125.1,180
19.33,1.025,0.5,1.025,1.533,180,120,180
19.34,0.9,0.5,1.05,1.471,154.2,120,180
19.35,1.025,0.5,1,1.517,180,120,180
19.36,0.9,0.55,0.925,1.403,154.2,123.4,157.7
19.37,1,0.575,0.925,1.479,180,125.1,157.7
19.38,0.975,0.625,1.2,1.668,167.2,128.7,180
19.39,1.025,0.675,1.25,1.752,180,132.5,180
19.40,1,0.525,1.15,1.612,180,121.7,180
19.41,1.05,0.55,0.95,1.519,180,123.4,161.8
19.42,0.975,0.5,1.05,1.518,167.2,120,180
19.43,0.975,0.6,0.975,1.504,167.2,126.9,167.2
19.44,1.025,0.475,0.9,1.444,180,118.4,154.2
19.45,0.925,0.575,0.925,1.429,157.7,125.1,157.7
19.46,0.975,0.575,1.075,1.561,167.2,125.1,180
19.47,1.075,0.675,1.275,1.799,180,132.5,180
19.48,1.225,0.675,1.375,1.961,180,132.5,180
19.49,1.125,0.625,1.325,1.847,180,128.7,180
19.50,1.05,0.7,1.2,1.741,180,134.4,180
19.51,1,0.65,1.2,1.692,180,130.5,180
19.52,1.025,0.575,0.85,1.45,180,125.1,148.2
19.53,0.975,0.5,0.775,1.342,167.2,120,140.8
19.54,0.925,0.55,0.875,1.387,157.7,123.4,151
19.55,1,0.525,1.125,1.594,180,121.7,180
19.56,1.05,0.65,1.175,1.705,180,130.5,180
19.57,1.025,0.6,1.25,1.724,180,126.9,180
19.58,1.05,0.675,1.175,1.714,180,132.5,180
19.59,1.025,0.625,1.15,1.662,180,128.7,180
19.60,0.975,0.65,1.125,1.624,167.2,130.5,180
19.61,0.975,0.625,0.975,1.514,167.2,128.7,167.2
19.62,1.025,0.575,0.95,1.511,180,125.1,161.8
19.63,0.975,0.6,1,1.52,167.2,126.9,180
19.64,1,0.5,1.025,1.517,180,120,180
19.65,0.975,0.7,0.925,1.515,167.2,134.4,157.7
19.66,1,0.525,0.95,1.476,180,121.7,161.8
19.67,0.975,0.65,1.075,1.59,167.2,130.5,180
19.68,1.075,0.575,1.275,1.764,180,125.1,180
19.69,1.025,0.65,1.325,1.797,180,130.5,180
19.70,1,0.625,0.975,1.53,180,128.7,167.2
19.71,0.875,0.525,0.925,1.377,151,121.7,157.7
19.72,0.9,0.65,0.975,1.478,154.2,130.5,167.2
19.73,0.975,0.525,1.05,1.526,167.2,121.7,180
19.74,0.95,0.625,0.975,1.498,161.8,128.7,167.2
19.75,0.925,0.55,1.025,1.486,157.7,123.4,180
19.76,0.925,0.625,1,1.499,157.7,128.7,180
19.77,0.925,0.575,1,1.479,157.7,125.1,180
19.78,1,0.65,1.075,1.606,180,130.5,180
19.79,0.95,0.575,1.2,1.635,161.8,125.1,180
19.80,0.9,0.7,1.05,1.55,154.2,134.4,180
19.81,0.9,0.575,1,1.463,154.2,125.1,180
19.82,0.85,0.575,0.925,1.382,148.2,125.1,157.7
19.83,0.875,0.575,0.925,1.397,151,125.1,157.7
19.84,0.925,0.525,1,1.46,157.7,121.7,180
19.85,0.925,0.575,1.025,1.496,157.7,125.1,180
19.86,0.9,0.525,1.075,1.497,154.2,121.7,180
19.87,0.925,0.6,1.1,1.557,157.7,126.9,180
19.88,0.925,0.625,1.125,1.585,157.7,128.7,180
19.89,0.95,0.725,1.175,1.676,161.8,136.5,180
19.90,0.975,0.575,1.2,1.65,167.2,125.1,180
19.91,0.925,0.625,1.05,1.533,157.7,128.7,180
19.92,0.925,0.475,0.975,1.425,157.7,118.4,167.2
19.93,0.875,0.575,0.95,1.414,151,125.1,161.8
19.94,0.925,0.525,0.95,1.426,157.7,121.7,161.8
19.95,0.875,0.6,1.025,1.475,151,126.9,180
19.96,0.9,0.525,1.05,1.479,154.2,121.7,180
19.97,0.975,0.575,0.95,1.478,167.2,125.1,161.8
19.98,0.875,0.575,1.025,1.465,151,125.1,180
19.99,0.95,0.5,1.1,1.537,161.8,120,180
20.00,0.95,0.6,1.075,1.555,161.8,126.9,180
```

To analyze the data I've employed the following code.

```
aa = Import[StringJoin[NotebookDirectory[], "LT3.csv"], "Data"];
aa[[1]]
Show[{ListLinePlot[Transpose[{aa[[All, 1]], aa[[All, 2]]}], 
   PlotRange -> {{15, 20}, {0, 1.5}}, ImageSize -> 650], 
  ListLinePlot[Transpose[{aa[[All, 1]], aa[[All, 3]]}], 
   PlotStyle -> Darker[Green]], 
  ListLinePlot[Transpose[{aa[[All, 1]], aa[[All, 4]]}], 
   PlotStyle -> Orange]}]
```

[image: Acceleration [xg] vs. time [s] for x (blue), y (green) and z (orange) axes.]

Next I considered the FFT.

```
ListLinePlot[Abs[Fourier[Rest@aa[[1000 ;; 2500, 2]]]], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 35}}, ImageSize -> 650]
```

[image: FFT of acceleration in x-plane]

Then I applied a moving average filter and graphed the result.

```
bb = Rest@aa;
adat = MovingAverage[bb, 100]
{ax, ay, az} = Interpolation /@ (adat[[All, {1, #}]] & /@ {2, 3, 4});
Plot[{ax[t], ay[t], az[t]}, {t, First@adat[[All, 1]], 
  Last@adat[[All, 1]]}, PlotLabel -> "Acceleration", Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Acceleration"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"x", "y", "z"}, ImageSize -> 650]
```

[image: Acceleration vs. Time]

Again, per [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63197/how-to-calculate-position-from-3-dimensional-acceleration-data) we have velocity vs. time

```
{vxt, vyt, 
   vzt} = (x /. 
      Quiet@First@
        NDSolve[{x[0] == 0, x'[t] == #[t]}, 
         x, {t, First@adat[[All, 1]], Last@adat[[All, 1]]}] & /@ {ax, 
     ay, az});
Plot[{vxt[t], vyt[t], vzt[t]}, {t, First@adat[[All, 1]], 
  Last@adat[[All, 1]]}, PlotLabel -> "Velocity", Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Velocity"}, PlotLegends -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
 ImageSize -> 650]
```

[image: Velocity vs. time]

And finally, position.

```
{xt, yt, zt} = (x /. Quiet@First@NDSolve[{x[0] == 0, x'[t] == #[t]}, x, {t, First@adat[[All, 1]], Last@adat[[All, 1]]}] & /@ {vxt, vyt, vzt});
Plot[{xt[t], yt[t], zt[t]}, {t, First@adat[[All, 1]], Last@adat[[All, 1]]}, PlotLabel -> "Position", Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Position"}, PlotLegends -> {"x", "y", "z"}, ImageSize -> 650]
```

[image: Position vs. time]

```
ParametricPlot3D[{xt[t], yt[t], zt[t]}, {t, First@adat[[All, 1]], Last@adat[[All, 1]]}, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}]
```

[image: Displacement in x, y and z planes]

Sorry for the long post but I wanted to be thorough. I've also tried alternative numerical integration methods but all lead to the same result. My guess is the integration error is accumulating with time. I realize the moving average filter is a halfhearted try but I have yet to identify an alternative filtering technique that works [reference](http://www-personal.engin.umd.umich.edu/~jwvm/current/Lance/LSlifkaThesis.doc). If anyone would like all of the original data or notebook I'd be happy to share.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you claiming that the numerical result disagrees with measured resuts? If so, I did not find the relevant part of the post, so you might want to make more clear what exactly is the troublesome aspect of the computations.

Comment: As @DanielLichtblau pointed out, it's not clear what problem you've identified. That said, what you're trying to do is tricky, at best. Since you're doubly integrating accelerometer data, biases become a major error source (the bias is the value that the sensor indicates when it's not accelerating). Furthermore, biases drift, so correcting for them is challenging. Add to that noise and other error sources, and you've got a tough problem.  Finally, you need to correct for the rotational motion of the earth...

Comment: Sorry. Since the accelerometer was rotated in the x-y plane I would expect the final result to be a circle.

Comment: You data has consistently large *z_g*, larger than the other components usually, which are all positive(!).  Have you correctly accounted for zero-point offset/bias?  Perhaps you need to use the degree information to account for the spinning.  I'm not that familiar with accelerometers, but the data or your interpretation of the data represented by your code looks wrong.  Any integration error seems secondary at this point.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem is one of physics (or electronics?), not *Mathematica*.

Comment: The reference frame of the accelerometer seems to be rotating along with the plank of wood (i.e., its orientation is not constant in space). So, it should measure a constant acceleration in the x and y directions and only the acceleration due to gravity in z, and thus the circular motion is in fact properly represented by what you plot. If you want to know the orientation of the accelerometer in space (which you surely do to recover the circle), you need a gyroscope or magnetometer (compass) as well. The question is interesting and nicely written, but I'm afraid I have to vote to close...

Comment: At the very least you should subtract the constant gravity vector. When it is not perfectly aligned with your sensor's z-axis its contributions will also leak through to the other axes in a periodic fashion. You also have to take into account that the measurements are in the sensor's frame of reference and you're plotting in a world fixed coordinate system.