# Integration of accelerometer data to x-y-z position

Tags: numerical-integration

Hi I have a list of accelerometer data, in their xyz acceleration values.
May I ask how can I integrate these data to get to the position in their xyz angle, assuming the initial velocity is zero and the frequency is 100Hz or 10ms.

The data collect from accelerometer X-axis is shown here.

```
ACCx= { -5.28524, -5.3143, -5.28402, -5.28449, -5.28687, -5.28712, -5.28764, -5.31481, -5.29336, -5.28679, -5.292, -5.28248, -5.28981, -5.31699, -5.29072, -5.27211, -5.30818, -5.28967, -5.26819, -5.29026, -5.29554, -5.29584, -5.2959, -5.291, -5.28629, -5.28641, -5.26754, -5.3153, -5.27695, -5.28782, -5.29712, -5.29061, -5.29799, -5.29322, -5.30743, -5.27493, -5.28909, -5.29415, -5.29432, -5.29945, -5.26592, -5.29483, -5.26407, -5.31667, -5.27127, -5.29318, -5.29741, -5.29562, -5.29098, -5.27721, -5.2963, -5.27264, -5.29671, -5.31171, -5.28048, -5.29035, -5.29546, -5.29571, -5.27411, -5.27218, -5.27952, -5.2965, -5.27971, -5.29634, -5.29633, -5.29841, -5.27244, -5.29637, -5.27764, -5.30153, -5.25389, -5.2965, -5.26978, -5.29634, -5.2676, -5.29648, -5.29647, -5.29141, -5.27245, -5.27248, -5.27062, -5.27294, -5.2731, -5.29424, -5.27131, -5.2951, -5.28789, -5.26679, -5.27196, -5.27708, -5.27437, -5.30109, -5.29625, -5.27465, -5.29645, -5.27494, -5.3017, -5.27518, -5.29698, -5.2804, -5.25458, -5.29749, -5.27593, -5.28375, -5.27394, -5.2971, -5.2979, -5.25534, -5.27413, -5.27934, -5.2984, -5.2817, -5.28468, -5.27711, -5.27517, -5.27548, -5.28071, -5.29963, -5.27595, -5.27841, -5.27937, -5.27686, -5.2721, -5.27725, -5.30634, -5.2827, -5.27568, -5.25434, -5.27844, -5.28073, -5.25983, -5.27656, -5.28379, -5.27907, -5.28934, -5.2774, -5.28977, -5.27997, -5.27795, -5.25926, -5.28314, -5.28058, -5.28369, -5.281, -5.25515, -5.2575, -5.28427, -5.27677, -5.28773, -5.25647, -5.26185, -5.2831, -5.25724, -5.2862, -5.28132, -5.28157, -5.28678, -5.26517, -5.28478, -5.26344, -5.28235, -5.28261, -5.25907, -5.25924, -5.28329, -5.26205, -5.26515, -5.26536, -5.26562, -5.28962, -5.28478, -5.28494, -5.26628, -5.26637, -5.28816, -5.28566, -5.29089, -5.26007, -5.26752, -5.26777, -5.28461, -5.27045, -5.28499, -5.28751, -5.27403, -5.28082, -5.26965, -5.29139, -5.28665, -5.26321, -5.29214, -5.27368, -5.27119, -5.26414, -5.2745, -5.26981, -5.27253, -5.27081, -5.33032, -5.23808, -5.25979, -5.30163, -5.27562, -5.29542, -5.27157, -5.29887, -5.27592, -5.27138, -5.26901, -5.27508, -5.28043, -5.30396, -5.26815, -5.27852, -5.27889, -5.27919, -5.30312, -5.27972, -5.27292, -5.27861, -5.30032, -5.27515, -5.27816, -5.2766, -5.30856, -5.27579, -5.28607, -5.24846, -5.28059, -5.31059, -5.29291, -5.29101, -5.29476, -5.28029, -5.26982, -5.31321, -5.28808, -5.31262, -5.28949, -5.31873, -5.29, -5.29013, -5.26868, -5.29253, -5.29334, -5.26706, -5.30143, -5.3182, -5.31332, -5.33689, -5.34879, -5.3425, -5.29275, -5.31777, -5.28375, -5.19364, -5.1703, -5.22877, -5.241, -5.26007, -5.28009, -5.27597, -5.28898, -5.28763, -5.31438, -5.29154, -5.33388, -5.283, -5.21323, -5.17995, -5.27719, -5.2615, -5.30976, -5.28652, -5.28652, -5.27721, -5.26623, -5.31147, -5.26135, -5.31298, -5.31719, -5.27961, -5.20919, -5.17786, -5.27197, -5.25857, -5.28992, -5.26414, -5.30929, -5.25975, -5.28381, -5.26535, -5.26552, -5.28215, -5.28456, -5.23698, -5.23425, -5.24738, -5.25915, -5.2622, -5.26558, -5.28214, -5.31155, -5.26453, -5.23113, -5.26334, -5.24491, -5.29349, -5.284, -5.24482, -5.23556, -5.29688, -5.26752, -5.27386, -5.27833, -5.27973, -5.30076, -5.25234, -5.28308, -5.27755, -5.258, -5.28632, -5.312, -5.28742, -5.29219, -5.32544, -5.26945, -5.30007, -5.29869, -5.32342, -5.32786, -5.30564, -5.32859, -5.28229, -5.31039, -5.29354, -5.31089, -5.33695, -5.30882, -5.31167, -5.33876, -5.31881, -5.34681, -5.32708, -5.32214, -5.33134, -5.32696, -5.3278, -5.30241, -5.34765, -5.32991, -5.31203, -5.32589, -5.30365, -5.37526, -5.31286, -5.32753, -5.33923, -5.33166, -5.34069, -5.3095, -5.32098, -5.34031, -5.31528, -5.36052, -5.31684, -5.34129, -5.33903, -5.33733, -5.34568, -5.34385, -5.32598, -5.32355, -5.33225, -5.32308, -5.35308, -5.32257, -5.3497, -5.34525, -5.35149, -5.34709, -5.35334, -5.32976, -5.33108, -5.33724, -5.37457, -5.33099, -5.36326, -5.35316, -5.33575, -5.34433, -5.3607, -5.34054, -5.33269, -5.36227, -5.33367, -5.36554, -5.33731, -5.36393, -5.35893, -5.33559, -5.36508, -5.33942, -5.3421, -5.34244, -5.35872, -5.34088, -5.33832, -5.37097, -5.36058, -5.35064, -5.35109, -5.3675, -5.3679, -5.34685, -5.36289, -5.3472, -5.35006, -5.34441, -5.3473, -5.34112, -5.36764, -5.34083, -5.34359, -5.34335, -5.35387, -5.3425, -5.3658, -5.33929, -5.34133, -5.3385, -5.335, -5.34532, -5.36054, -5.33038, -5.30657, -5.33206, -5.33691, -5.31273, -5.33051, -5.31723, -5.34039, -5.35556, -5.31308, -5.33859, -5.33258, -5.33217, -5.33184, -5.31072, -5.32852, -5.33591, -5.34829, -5.32443, -5.3296, -5.32133, -5.32646, -5.29945, -5.32028, -5.33077, -5.32195, -5.30073, -5.34777, -5.32628, -5.29973, -5.32049, -5.32262, -5.32513, -5.31892, -5.32963, -5.30283, -5.29716, -5.31495, -5.29626, -5.31961, -5.31936, -5.31903, -5.31632, -5.2978, -5.29721, -5.29212, -5.29993, -5.29697, -5.3126, -5.31779, -5.29941, -5.31511, -5.28851, -5.32297, -5.29673, -5.32044, -5.29399, -5.29684, -5.32331, -5.29192, -5.31274, -5.32098, -5.29716, -5.30995, -5.34151, -5.29147, -5.29136, -5.28609, -5.31247, -5.29707, -5.29157, -5.31523, -5.29409, -5.31235, -5.29699, -5.29163, -5.297, -5.31281, -5.31549, -5.2918, -5.29175, -5.29179, -5.29196, -5.30004, -5.3211, -5.29752, -5.26858, -5.31596, -5.27409, -5.30032, -5.31081, -5.29815, -5.29832, -5.28773, -5.29335, -5.28826, -5.31754, -5.27573, -5.31773, -5.32067, -5.27604, -5.29155, -5.32103, -5.3184, -5.29768, -5.3186, -5.3005, -5.32978, -5.2639, -5.29332, -5.31988, -5.27554, -5.29118, -5.29704, -5.29688, -5.27066, -5.29454, -5.31833, -5.29467, -5.30029, -5.29767, -5.2746, -5.27463, -5.29572, -5.29863, -5.31999, -5.27288, -5.29676, -5.2915, -5.30263, -5.30015, -5.29514, -5.29791, -5.29806, -5.30634, -5.27779, -5.3044, -5.27561, -5.27333, -5.32356, -5.30555, -5.30027, -5.27419, -5.29805, -5.27719, -5.30628, -5.30073, -5.30092, -5.30116, -5.27775, -5.32276, -5.25758, -5.30242, -5.28713, -5.28194, -5.30045, -5.27421, -5.28008, -5.30156, -5.30741, -5.27864, -5.30262, -5.28742, -5.30316, -5.25896, -5.30392, -5.28336, -5.30195, -5.31061, -5.28735, -5.30031, -5.28251, -5.28299, -5.31797, -5.3129, -5.28142, -5.31354, -5.29038, -5.28534, -5.28857, -5.29191, -5.31047, -5.29554, -5.28776, -5.31201, -5.26544, -5.29261, -5.30576, -5.29897, -5.29415, -5.31541, -5.3188, -5.29295, -5.2963, -5.28849, -5.29738, -5.29789, -5.30661, -5.29895, -5.29659, -5.30262, -5.29504, -5.32748, -5.28371, -5.3023, -5.31259, -5.30326, -5.30658, -5.3045, -5.29665, -5.30285, -5.32419, -5.30102, -5.33058, -5.32533, -5.29632, -5.30755, -5.27584, -5.30787, -5.32599, -5.29689, -5.28458, -5.32644, -5.27926, -5.27932, -5.3113, -5.30875, -5.30642, -5.3042, -5.32829, -5.28688, -5.30247, -5.30832, -5.335, -5.2853, -5.30358, -5.3121, -5.31235, -5.28617, -5.30443, -5.2867, -5.31338, -5.29989, -5.31431, -5.28567, -5.2913, -5.31239, -5.30702, -5.31844, -5.25769, -5.33153, -5.28725, -5.31112, -5.26117, -5.30842, -5.29044, -5.30868, -5.31168, -5.29372, -5.30638, -5.3094, -5.30404, -5.28621, -5.31562, -5.31579, -5.28672, -5.31616, -5.28727, -5.31382, -5.31659, -5.28462, -5.28736, -5.29021, -5.31931, -5.28752, -5.28496, -5.29618, -5.30897, -5.31771, -5.29449, -5.29216, -5.29265, -5.31919, -5.28466, -5.28495, -5.31714, -5.29652, -5.29113, -5.32041, -5.29152, -5.31529, -5.29171, -5.29473, -5.31844, -5.29491, -5.3214, -5.29227, -5.29524, -5.28972, -5.27174, -5.29262, -5.29269, -5.28994, -5.30401, -5.29022, -5.29034, -5.26692, -5.29634, -5.28796, -5.31166, -5.3229, -5.2908, -5.31708, -5.29049, -5.26688, -5.3253, -5.29306, -5.29572, -5.29009, -5.2665, -5.29582, -5.29024, -5.31092, -5.27489, -5.29579, -5.29304, -5.28746, -5.29588, -5.29028, -5.28079, -5.3112, -5.31983, -5.26436, -5.26452, -5.31183, -5.29114, -5.27055, -5.3124, -5.27383, -5.2976, -5.28941, -5.28949, -5.29807, -5.29531, -5.28986, -5.27754, -5.29275, -5.2931, -5.29316, -5.27249, -5.29617, -5.29624, -5.26706, -5.31444, -5.27305, -5.31748, -5.26478, -5.29701, -5.27355, -5.27358, -5.29729, -5.28628, -5.29502, -5.2745, -5.29263, -5.29855, -5.29316, -5.27543, -5.29634, -5.27279, -5.28796, -5.27853, -5.2937, -5.29077, -5.27867, -5.29106, -5.27895, -5.29429, -5.29167, -5.24472, -5.29209, -5.27445, -5.29548, , -5.29931, -5.27328, -5.27082, -5.30039, -5.30351, -5.24806, , -5.25544, -5.30282, -5.27947, -5.27972, -5.27413, -5.26236, -5.27725, -5.25714, -5.25435, -5.27798, -5.27532, -5.26054, -5.27267, -5.26082, -5.2728, -5.25242, -5.27298, -5.28211, -5.25564, -5.26754, -5.26151, -5.25579, -5.2972, -5.26195, -5.27987, -5.28022, -5.28623, -5.27785, -5.228, -5.28118, -5.27889, -5.25245, -5.25838, -5.27647, -5.26794, -5.26537, -5.251, -5.2869, -5.26085, -5.2848, -5.23499, -5.25612, -5.30034, -5.20408, -5.28896, -5.24604, -5.32217, -5.24382, -5.27625, -5.26551, -5.28273, -5.29514, -5.25712, -5.26056, -5.26364, -5.26108, -5.26394, -5.25841, -5.2853, -5.28547, -5.26497, -5.28871, -5.26847, -5.27146, -5.26584, -5.2983, -5.25726, -5.28947, -5.29268, -5.23676, -5.28974, -5.24019, -5.29022, -5.29054, -5.27043, -5.24408, -5.27053, -5.26802, -5.26508, -5.26842, -5.29223, -5.26896, -5.26332, -5.27226, -5.25208, -5.26398, -5.24669, -5.26171, -5.2947, -5.2683, -5.27158, -5.26287, -5.27811, -5.29021, -5.25795, -5.27309, -5.27043, -5.26808, -5.27695, -5.2687, -5.27498, -5.27538, -5.29931, -5.29073, -5.2766, -5.30039, -5.2389, -5.27767, -5.28382, -5.28941, -5.27522, -5.25507, -5.28134, -5.2462, -5.27305, -5.28185, -5.28206, -5.27365, -5.28242, -5.29446, -5.27717, -5.28054, -5.25414, -5.28364, -5.30137, -5.27533, -5.27235, -5.27577, -5.27862, -5.27279, -5.2788, -5.279, -5.27008, -5.24981, -5.24944, -5.28272, -5.28246, -5.24733, -5.28016, -5.27448, -5.28335, -5.25736, -5.27818, -5.28389, -5.275, -5.28133, -5.25471, -5.28413, -5.25478, -5.27242, -5.28174, -5.27869, -5.25854, -5.28486, -5.26152, -5.25572, -5.24993, -5.23265, -5.26228, -5.28603, -5.2805, -5.25128, -5.28075, -5.25746, -5.27527, -5.25811, -5.25832, -5.27913, -5.28206, -5.27317, -5.25576, -5.25326, -5.28296, -5.25387, -5.26282, -5.284, -5.255, -5.25521, -5.26735, -5.28204, -5.28566, -5.25652, -5.25941, -5.27701, -5.25684, -5.28047, -5.27463, -5.23861, -5.28885, -5.25319, -5.26222, -5.26506, -5.24551, -5.25912, -5.26327, -5.29494, -5.27007, -5.25214, -5.26461, -5.28275, -5.27458, -5.26074, -5.29058, -5.27943, -5.24132, -5.26271, -5.26329, -5.26979, -5.24377, -5.2943, -5.24577, -5.27362, -5.26567, -5.2994, -5.29396, -5.27347, -5.27341, -5.27915, -5.22888, -5.26198, -5.27714, -5.25839, -5.26944, -5.27644, -5.28196, -5.2981, -5.28301, -5.25797, -5.26849, -5.27381, -5.28377, -5.3276, -5.30931, -5.31505, -5.32269, -5.30329, -5.32155, -5.29559, -5.24937, -5.29714, -5.31823, -5.27214, -5.31191, -5.29435, -5.29503, -5.30458, -5.28829, -5.30254, -5.29851, -5.29566, -5.31313, -5.31265, -5.27068, -5.28263, -5.32922, -5.31504, -5.3117, -5.28786, -5.28749, -5.3043, -5.27992, -5.33256, -5.26549, -5.27914, -5.2791, -5.2888, -5.30136, -5.24984, -5.28003, -5.29469, -5.28298, -5.26355, -5.27999, -5.26462, -5.2912, -5.25645, -5.41575, -5.36563, -5.53795, -5.65297, -5.85562, -6.01857, -6.35224, -7.69013, -13.3589, -20.0815, -23.4458, -23.9918, -19.6571, -16.543, -15.9769, -17.019, -17.7854, -17.5157, -16.8044, -16.2496, -16.1958, -16.3423, -16.0191, -15.5887, -15.0839, -14.6473, -14.3779, -14.1698, -14.0691, -14.0202, -13.9982, -13.799, -13.4981, -13.0837, -12.6108, -12.0628, -11.3795, -10.5981, -9.70178, -8.52406, -7.17819, -5.98919, -5.54917, -4.99117, -4.16916, -3.50414, -3.16635, -3.10822, -3.37472, -3.93027, -4.50284, -5.03682, -5.50542, -5.85911, -5.98092, -5.8766, -5.61102, -5.32905, -5.10938, -4.92118, -4.82358, -4.78616, -5.60728, -8.07198, -10.2496, -11.1089, -11.3127, -10.9826, -11.9766, -12.9812, -12.4925, -10.9781, -9.80843, -9.74928, -11.0816, -14.2428, -15.9764, -16.4452, -15.9658, -15.2252, -15.0078, -15.4186, -16.7155, -17.8981, -18.1536, -18.1618, -18.7642, -21.1437, -18.406, -18.2013, -17.5777, -17.914, -18.2378, -18.1462, -17.8612, -17.5983, -17.5785, -17.867, -18.3568, -18.9765, -19.4271, -19.6865, -19.816, -19.6708, -19.0157, -18.2814, -17.3412, -16.4033, -15.41, -14.3986, -13.5259, -12.7804, -12.2116, -11.7362, -11.2369, -10.6639, -9.94549, -9.23263, -8.57811, -8.05549, -7.73476, -7.54264, -7.46419, -7.42665, -7.31543, -7.19141, -7.09283, -6.99682, -6.98272, -7.10534, -7.26477, -7.65172, -7.96988, -8.36142, -8.86562, -9.42908, -10.0802, -11.1186, -12.6064, -13.9994, -15.0491, -15.7378, -16.5292, -17.8851, -18.5875, -18.0127, -16.7207, -15.9846, -16.8256, -19.3202, -21.2291, -21.7544, -20.6845, -19.3004, -17.9845, -16.9157, -16.2935, -16.2754, -16.3859, -16.711, -17.0521, -17.8895, -30.6518, 0.384415, -12.7042, -12.6141, -16.2623, -18.1903, -18.5329, -17.4384, -16.1016, -15.4507, -14.9868, -14.5592, -14.2206, -13.7747, -13.9058, -14.6457, -16.1488, -18.128, -18.757, -17.6524, -15.4071, -12.6591, -9.77616, -7.20579, -5.13069, -3.61145, -2.41304, -1.45846, -1.67002, -3.37427, -4.41475, -3.84769, -2.46697, -0.884216, -0.102408, 0.136, 0.267402, -0.333666, -0.721668, -1.23177, -2.261, -3.69889, -5.30348, -5.82226, -6.24093, -6.88539, -7.64177, -9.09216, -9.96375, -11.0806, -11.7785, -12.6109, -14.7284, -16.4073, -16.9566, -17.5098, -18.0862, -19.3741, -20.5762, -20.5352, -20.2193, -20.181, -20.2577, -20.5579, -20.9779, -21.0203, -20.4778, -19.7684, -19.0357, -19.0053, -19.2877, -19.84, -20.5866, -21.3373, -22.0454, -22.5821, -22.9696, -23.1796, -23.3276, -23.315, -23.3281, -23.1331, -22.7593, -22.2095, -21.3262, -20.2135, -19.0954, -17.6772, -16.1836, -14.6213, -12.7619, -10.9395, -9.51677, -8.821, -8.83479, -9.16674, -9.70429, -10.2125, -10.4901, -10.592, -10.5699, -10.2519, -9.8239, -9.44713, -9.0993, -9.1064, -9.68756, -10.7315, -11.6457, -12.0042, -11.9414, -11.7442, -11.9449, -13.433, -15.0291, -16.136, -16.5425, -17.1035, -18.5302, -19.0485, -18.4317, -16.5455, -16.7404, -19.1648, -23.1503, -23.3605, -21.3142, -18.2315, -15.7276, -14.6404, -14.7236, -15.4211, -15.9593, -16.14, -15.7312, -18.0223, -11.5954, -13.6334, -14.5449, -14.2745, -13.0146, -11.8028, -10.9507, -10.4528, -10.0401, -9.95237, -10.0271, -10.2716, -10.6931, -11.1051, -11.399, -11.5671, -11.8436, -11.6785, -11.6991, -11.7142, -11.6568, -11.4478, -10.947, -10.4032, -9.57096, -8.65049, -7.6188, -6.66126, -6.70051, -6.92652, -6.24149, -5.21711, -4.42597, -4.20865, -4.66971, -5.6483, -6.19139, -6.19397, -6.81477, -8.06761, -10.6509, -13.1363, -11.5723, -8.41528, -5.77523, -5.65733, -9.5516, -12.1743, -12.507, -11.6061, -10.9337, -12.3231, -15.1603, -17.6778, -18.5509, -17.5826, -16.6073, -16.8697, -19.157, -22.6931, -24.0973, -22.8723, -21.3146, -20.3399, -19.9202, -20.0403, -20.9245, -21.0998, -20.301, -19.1153, -18.7987, -19.0723, -20.171, -22.5522, -25.6681, -26.9537, -24.7704, -21.2392, -17.8035, -15.291, -14.0893, -13.9977, -14.3111, -14.6864, -14.7438, -14.3931, -13.782, -13.1032, -12.555, -12.3994, -12.269, -11.8547, -11.2555, -10.6082, -10.3059, -10.406, -10.3275, -9.91364, -9.51886, -9.26148, -9.21443, -9.90777, -10.8465, -11.1539, -10.8231, -10.6583, -10.8062, -11.2797, -11.8201, -12.214, -12.5585, -13.2675, -14.3401, -15.7661, -18.0072, -19.206, -17.6617, -16.8575, -16.8434, -16.0417, -14.7781, -10.9036, -7.88071, -8.49888, -9.9082, -9.9043, -8.47559, -5.74595, -3.70074, -3.04047, -3.03493, -3.47452, -3.7036, -3.10577, -2.59556, -2.54728, -3.13822, -3.49712, -3.13685, -2.24175, -0.379368, 0.13843, -0.345912, -0.417616, -0.987015, -2.1506, -3.92927, -5.17017, -3.78709, -9.43523, -16.5012, 13.0086, -3.84916, -9.63685, -10.4649, -11.2414, -6.2937, -5.89073, -8.99391, -9.50594, -7.1328, -6.91465, -7.9083, -7.93516, -6.45905, -7.22385, -6.73971, -7.62268, -7.69024, -7.75643, -7.82357, -7.92653, -7.9547, -7.86586, -7.70365, -7.48586, -7.29653, -7.12815, -6.99691, -6.90363, -6.71062, -6.67211, -6.57953, -6.83182, -7.11945, -7.13573, -7.2101, -7.20061, -7.15833, -7.11627, -7.08088, -7.00489, -6.89487, -6.82215, -6.85184, -7.01273, -7.15432, -7.13803, -7.24394, -7.47793, -7.53086, -8.09685, -8.48364, -8.8601, -9.68949, -10.8073, -11.7742, -14.1357, -16.4751, -13.7348, -9.53439, -5.29663, 0.062731, -16.4762, 1.86537, 10.7456, 9.15193, 7.68961, 7.95965, 6.65339, 5.21104, 3.96093, 2.3605, 1.46772, -0.962658, -5.09146, -8.08246, -9.49272, -9.97955, -10.4335, -11.2491, -12.1959, -12.8787, -14.1255, -15.4655, -16.5368, -17.3542, -17.7618, -18.0292, -18.9855, -20.0333, -20.6598, -21.4895, -21.9842, -22.3244, -22.371, -21.8032, -20.8987, -19.8612, -18.7839, -17.607, -16.5233, -15.583, -13.8078, -11.9801, -10.4455, -8.95032, -7.66302, -6.86593, -6.48942, -6.52396, -6.997, -7.91335, -8.66974, -8.89057, -8.82653, -8.51127, -7.94379, -7.45749, -6.92457, -6.59954, -6.48561, -6.81627, -7.26358, -7.78394, -8.37484, -9.01798, -9.48686, -10.1858, -11.3765, -11.7962, -11.4778, -11.1069, -11.9469, -13.7803, -15.2486, -15.7095, -15.2687, -14.8366, -14.9607, -15.6812, -17.521, -19.0682, -18.6664, -17.8108, -17.7984, -18.1872, -18.0386, -17.2813, -15.8315, -14.5791, -14.269, -15.2075, -16.8589, -18.372, -17.251, -14.8675, -13.0687, -12.738, -13.4306, -14.1008, -14.2982, -14.2822, -14.237, -13.9743, -13.5664, -13.171, -12.7881, -12.2245, -11.643, -11.2538, -11.0573, -11.1258, -11.35, -11.6071, -11.7524, -11.6491, -11.3461, -10.9817, -10.3084, -9.86971, -9.79508, -9.9724, -10.4296, -10.9442, -11.201, -11.057, -10.5565, -9.62528, -8.29106, -6.91766, -5.77104, -4.86653, -4.1737, -3.70728, -3.47867, -3.44698, -3.64026, -4.1996, -4.83858, -5.35504, -5.85469, -7.12269, -8.21365, -8.68055, -8.94863, -9.45254, -9.76442, -10.8805, -12.1171, -12.5724, -14.1183, -14.7025, -14.6332, -13.9449, -12.1151, -11.3663, -11.9289, -14.9562, -18.4373, -18.956, -18.9324, -17.8972, -16.562, -27.8675, -19.5248, -7.19589, -21.1409, -15.4915, -16.3578, -16.252, -16.6263, -18.5395, -19.5515, -19.5935, -19.202, -18.6936, -18.5736, -18.6144, -18.7266, -18.9662, -19.1579, -19.1517, -19.3235, -19.7798, -20.0583, -20.0594, -19.8024, -19.3474, -18.7244, -17.8918, -17.0266, -16.1506, -15.0421, -14.0403, -12.7693, -11.4868, -10.4314, -9.55986, -8.81466, -8.31118, -7.90808, -7.75752, -7.86646, -8.1459, -8.47397, -8.54082, -8.43046, -8.10013, -7.64236, -7.15844, -6.86712, -6.8023, -7.28685, -8.45586, -9.38891, -9.75485, -9.52807, -9.10491, -8.73941, -9.13725, -10.1892, -11.351, -12.4321, -13.1673, -13.6641, -14.4564, -14.8402, -15.866, -17.5266, -19.2938, -19.9351, -18.5137, -16.8151, -15.7315, -15.8766, -17.3915, -20.1875, -22.2842, -21.2136, -18.5708, -16.8557, -15.6626, -14.6903, -14.2089, -14.141, -14.5092, -15.5477, -19.5029, -3.98503, -10.1792, -13.6517, -13.4768, -11.8733, -10.5957, -10.1761, -10.2471, -10.3565, -10.0673, -9.50493, -8.83317, -8.16984, -7.48196, -7.11051, -6.7887, -6.1428, -5.35621, -4.58407, -3.89331, -3.48764, -3.27689, -2.93183, -2.53151, -2.14058, -1.77607, -1.45137, -1.59591, -2.06314, -1.99025, -1.6235, -1.39095, -1.44542, -1.63726, -1.69812, -1.69339, -1.74335, -1.87828, -2.2268, -2.53319, -2.94153, -3.32732, -3.57791, -3.81507, -4.00064, -4.32978, -4.64458, -4.94305, -5.06899, -5.42252, -6.21486, -6.87533, -7.496, -8.00456, -8.12149, -8.05192, -8.10799, -8.61049, -9.47982, -9.98443, -10.5491, -10.8284, -10.937, -11.3523, -11.8194, -11.7712, -11.7609, -11.9069, -12.2899, -12.4112, -12.3242, -12.0001, -12.4485, -13.6254, -15.5061, -17.4447, -18.0967, -18.0053, -17.9044, -17.9967, -17.9465, -18.0131, -18.0216, -17.9983, -17.529, -17.2453, -16.8124, -16.1825, -15.4834, -14.7795, -14.0771, -13.5253, -13.0623, -12.7329, -12.4496, -12.1956, -11.9501, -11.6206, -11.2335, -10.789, -10.2355, -9.7921, -9.4316, -9.29655, -9.19527, -9.17782, -9.17254, -9.11498, -8.96079, -8.70268, -8.36487, -8.09005, -7.99186, -8.12994, -8.37638, -8.76539, -9.46329, -10.0065, -10.5003, -11.0087, -11.2911, -11.4696, -11.8949, -13.2268, -15.0663, -16.2285, -16.8191, -17.1152, -17.5777, -18.96, -19.7946, -19.9516, -19.7469, -20.8009, -25.0063, -27.547, -24.958, -20.2748, -16.8982, -17.4004, -20.6386, -21.745, -19.9942, -17.1547, -15.3775, -15.0233, -15.4845, -15.9756, -15.9621, -15.2675, -14.3317, -13.7445, -13.1561, -12.5731, -11.9582, -11.2793, -10.3635, -9.21967, -8.37388, -7.92681, -7.63936, -7.30625, -6.87229, -6.17027, -5.39932, -4.77376, -4.72252, -5.26578, -5.54283, -6.29273, -6.75948, -6.43, -5.61922, -3.90352, -1.90749, -0.095032, 1.15503, 1.57666, 1.25058, 0.700358, 0.310171, -0.031409, -0.164526, -0.187981, -0.200952, -0.180125, -0.32904, -0.716891, -1.29214, -2.02704, -3.12258, -5.28578, -7.74922, -9.57896, -10.9702, -11.9951, -12.2985, -12.0986, -11.7444, -11.6449, -11.9656, -13.1278, -14.6538, -15.5484, -15.8502, -16.0744, -16.4302, -17.2024, -18.9107, -19.8691, -20.2953, -20.4699, -20.1447, -60.2494, -6.50462, -1.98086, -13.9753, -13.2339, -17.3881, -17.6495, -18.8807, -20.196, -20.7459, -20.8081, -19.9112, -18.1706, -16.6681, -15.9616, -15.7548, -15.7541, -15.5576, -15.5106, -16.0309, -16.629, -16.5601, -15.7139, -14.4938, -13.7276, -13.5372, -13.2575, -12.6866, -11.7381, -10.9118, -10.6717, -10.9369, -11.3803, -10.9524, -9.83833, -8.78597, -8.29278, -8.36552, -8.50606, -8.33256, -7.83191, -7.52355, -7.60531, -7.7057, -7.84813, -7.79189, -7.6146, -7.70331, -8.01383, -8.64757, -9.1759, -8.99797, -8.36578, -7.06286, -6.05829, -5.52051, -4.88114, -4.2841, -3.71381, -2.64306, -1.26037, -0.334396, -0.252203, -0.464717, 0.340884, 1.21382, 1.62656, 1.45614, 0.876576, 0.470566, 0.431924, 0.687257, 0.960802, 0.484289, -0.66706, 7.59444, 5.39044, 0.536022, 1.44295, -4.53937,  -6.95982, -6.97845, -4.87928, -6.39909, -8.53981, -5.20784, -6.33014, -5.78438, -5.38368, -5.04457, -5.58878, -5.42675, -5.46676, -5.25136, -5.25273, -5.28058, -5.3178, -5.43134, -5.36382, -5.36077, -5.29444, -5.28387, -5.31534, -5.34184, -5.34813, -5.33891, -5.35383, -5.33744, -5.35328, -5.33071, -5.36524, -5.35986, -5.36284, -5.33532, -5.37316, -5.33571, -5.30987, -5.32775, -5.34337, -5.34654, -5.36026, -5.35102, -5.23079, -5.22482, -5.1904, -5.27439, -5.32764, -5.33981, -5.29968, -5.358, -5.30103, -5.27758, -5.28802, -5.30848, -5.32686, -5.2906, -5.31853, -5.33257, -5.30757, -5.29024, -5.26994, -5.27464, -5.30742,  }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63197/10397)? Please do explain what is exactly the problem you are facing. Is it with the physics and mathematics or is it really about Wolfram Mathematica programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I add a time coordinate assuming that when you say frequency is 100 Hz you mean that the sample rate is 100 samples per second.

```
sr = 100;
ax = Table[{(n - 1) 1/sr, ACCx[[n]]}, {n, Length@ACCx}];
te = ax[[-1, 1]];
```

Here te is the end time.
The next stage is to interpolate the data and produce a function that can be plotted.

```
axi = Interpolation[ax];
Plot[axi[t], {t, 0, te}]
```

[image]

Your acceleration seems to be approximately constant with a burst of noise between 14 seconds and 25 seconds where the negative values are probably clipped at -22 m/s^2.

Now we have to integrate acceleration to get velocity and then integrate velocity to get displacement. This is done as follows

```
ClearAll[vx, sx, v, s, t];
{sx, vx} = {s, s'} /. 
  First@NDSolve[{s''[t] == axi[t], s'[0] == 0, s[0] == 0}, {s, 
     s'}, {t, 0, te}]
```

Here vx is the velocity and sx the displacement. Both of these functions can be plotted or used elsewhere.

```
Plot[vx[t], {t, 0, te}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[sx[t], {t, 0, te}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Hope that helps.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You will know that the velocity is v= v0+ integrate(acceleration) and the path is x= x0+ integrate(velocity). For discrete data we can integrate using the function "Accumulate". BTW you should not use capitalize variable names, they are reserved for the system.

```
v = Accumulate[Prepend[accx/2, 0]] 0.01;
x = Accumulate[v] 0.01;
ListLinePlot[{x, v}]
```

[image]